# Why is there a difference between hash results of nodeJs bcrypt and dotNet version

Tags: node.js, .net, bcrypt

So the resulting hashes (using same number of salt rounds) are different, here is what i used :

NodeJs implementation :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

dotNet implementation :
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Both resulting hashes start with `$2a$12$` indicating we use same bcrypt version and same number of salt rounds but the results are different for same input.

Anyone has any idea why?

So first 3 times i'm checking if hashed passwords match using `BCrypt.CheckPassword` and next 3 i'm comparing with hashes generated in nodeJs

```
            string password = "SomePassword";

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
            password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);


            //string candidate = "$2a$12$zDG1M72eRg9FAeSEJrVNNeJYh0Fa3DsuAP9nBa.IDgbDQLOw.525O";
            string candidate = "SomePassword";

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            string hashed;
            bool matches;

            hashed = BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
            Console.WriteLine(hashed);
            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, hashed);
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());

            hashed = BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
            Console.WriteLine(hashed);
            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, hashed);
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());

            hashed = BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
            Console.WriteLine(hashed);
            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, hashed);
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());


            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, "$2a$12$wnCnB5lEX8XT.QUnYVmzQ.pCC03QobNZ2uxDz17BASn03maFfnWGq");
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());
            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, "$2a$12$eYbwrN6P.BYc.4NncivrQeOEGeXBKGwPcfnEGRSOgKJfWzZoO9auu");
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());
            matches = BCrypt.CheckPassword(candidate, "$2a$12$kKaPRy9u9w.1Jjh/aG5PfuT3IohSDFIG/1B2i7twE9huGwAR/kMTm");
            Console.WriteLine(matches.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
```

output :

```
$2a$12$Yl3IO09nJ.dTc621yjvH5uUz7TOz/UjziEI5lZuNW6dED.K0GlOSC
True
$2a$12$t8ruHd0FrKNazO/t3j0dP.KG683vjyqiE7lErC7iQfwAxK6pLASG.
True
$2a$12$ZhbyzBh956Mxps9Y5pho9e.age8oj3VsJjf4ScWpv0nilSNx00Axq
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Could you please add your code and output as text to the question, rather than as images?

Comment: @phuzi done. thx!

Comment: Can you confirm what BCrypt utility you are using? I've tried your code above with the BCrypt.cs located on the linked dotnet implementation page and I always get "True" echoed to the console - they all match!

Comment: @phuzi somewhere on the way as i was updating this issue it started working for me too. I think i was comparing hash with hash rather then password with hash.
I'll leave this question on if anyone runs into similar doubts and upvote your answer so you get some credit for the effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you do the check you are using a different salts which are included in the password hash, so this approach will never work.

What you should be doing is using `BCrypt.Verify(password, hash)` which will use the same version, number of salt rounds and salt to verify whether the password is valid.

It also appears that the password hash has extra spaces in it...

```
var password = "Dule1Savic";

var hash = "$2a$12$rmrr0tLPKOpX7BI1XEZj3.rn8US.J8Cm13A/eHm3uzg70XXzaMHSi";

var isMatch = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, hash);

Console.WriteLine(isMatch); // True
```

Comment: i'm doing that using `BCrypt.CheckPassword`